# Mark questions or answers as out of date?

Tags: feature-request, answers, accepted-answer

It would really help for finding relevant answers if there was a way to mark questions and answers as out of date.

I have been searching SO for various questions and have often found that there are answers and questions which are no longer relevant as they are for older versions of libraries, frameworks etc.  I don't really think a new question should be asked as it is effectively a duplicate with "in version X" added and will just add more and more questions which isn't needed.  I have a couple of ideas:

1. Mark answers or questions which are for an older version (i.e. no longer the correct answer)
2. Allow multiple accepted answers and specify versions via tags per answer
3. Specify some sort of "applies to versions" tag
4. Be able to search for / filter answers based on any of the above suggestions

I know tags can be modified and there are some tags for specific versions of libraries but more often than not questions are tagged with just a generic tag for the framework or library and do not specify the version. And there is currently no way to add tags to answers.

Comment: You shouldn't flag posts like these. Flags should not be used for issues related to technical accuracy.

Comment: Just because a given question/answer only applies to older versions of a product doesn't mean it's meaningless.  Plenty of people go around using older versions pretty much every possible product.

Comment: @Lix In this case "flag" is used as just a generic term to "mark" or otherwise signify something... in this case being out of date.

Comment: @Servy I agree questions and answers for old versions are still valuable.  Indeed I'd like to have a method to make it more obvious that a question or answer is for particular versions.

Comment: @kjbartel - flagging anywhere on [se] means that this post requires moderator attention. If this was not your intention, perhaps you should consider re-wording that point to something that doesn't suggest an already existing feature...

Comment: @Lix Ok. Reworded. Hope it makes more sense.
Personally I feel the word "flag" is quite a common meaning in programming / computing in general so it's a bit limited to have it just mean "flag for moderator attention".  In actual fact "flag" is the best English word here as it is supposed to bring to the attention of  users and moderators that an answer only applies to a specific version.

Comment: A very good request, imho. Here's an issue showing this need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740660/why-does-the-empty-string-not-match-as-seq-empty which is essentially a bug find in Scala 2.7, fixed about four years ago in Scala 2.8, it seems. Today, all uses I am aware of are Scala 2.9 and later (current is 2.11). This showed up in my search today, that's why it matters. Irrelevant noise that could really be marked as 'ancient' / 'expired' / 'no more relevant'. The need for such a mechanism will grow in importance as the time passes.

Comment: @akauppi Exactly. So much noise in results. What are you supposed to do when you get an old result? Check if it actually works and applies to you and then maybe change the tag on it to specify the version? But most people won't do this so the next person who finds the out of date answer goes through the same process of finding it doesn't work. A simple way to just say "This is old and no longer correct" would make this site so much more useful.

Comment: 4 years later and nothing has changed... The older SO gets, the more relevant this issue is.

Comment: [Introducing Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405302/3404097) [tag:outdated-answer]

Answer (score 13):

If you find a question that is out of date; or the answers to a question are out of date, you have a few things you can do:

1. Leave a comment on the accepted answer or the question stated that this solution *no longer works*.
2. Keep searching. Quite possibly someone else has noticed this and has posted a question on the subject.  If you find that question, Bob's your uncle.
3. Ask a new question, noting *in your question* the questions you've looked at that were out of date. This is *really* important, and it'll keep your question from being closed as a duplicate.  It's also important to note *why* they are out of date, and include a minimal example that shows they're out of date. (Code written for and tested against both versions, and the outcome showing it's out of date).
4. If you know the answer, feel free to edit the existing accepted answer or add your own answer that updates the solution for the newest version.

Comment: Generally this is exactly what I am currently doing. Mostly I find the answer I'm looking for on another website or work it out for myself.  I therefore do not ask another question "for version X".  I have added answers to a couple of questions for newer versions. I think it's actually better to have answers on the same question rather than new questions as it makes it better as a single reference. But the problem is that the questions and answers which are at the top are going to be ones with high votes (and generally older), so it makes SO have less value as a resource for new versions.

Comment: -1 for "*edit the existing accepted answer [...] that updates the solution for the newest version*", unless you meant just an [editor's note](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265440/372643). Changing the meaning of someone else's answer isn't the role of an editor. (Also discussed [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265749/372643).)

Comment: That's not what the CC is for, especially the way answers are presented. Each answer clearly states "answered [date] (by) [username]". Misrepresenting what the answerer said is just bad practice, and quite possibly in breach of the CC licence. The "plain text" licence says "*You may do so in any reasonable manner, but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your use.*", editing someone else's answer to change its meaning goes against that. (And no, don't expect readers to go through the entire revision history.)

Comment: @Bruno I take it [you haven't read the canonical answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) on this subject?

Comment: It's not a canonical answer, it's a blog (no real discussion like on Meta). This would only really work with CW, which is frankly a concept that has never fully worked. In addition, unfortunately, whatever Joel and Jeff may think they've tried to do, they didn't get it completely right in that respect. Whatever the SE blogs say doesn't mean it's licence compliant, SE is still not allowed to misrepresent what an answer's author said. Minor edits are fine. Changes that change the meaning are a no-no unless it's very clear this is no longer from the original author.

Answer (score 11):

Questions and answers about legacy versions of tools should remain on Stack Overflow.  Plenty of people maintain older code.  When they are using such legacy versions, the various other support channels are often discontinued and SO becomes even more relevant.

It's very useful to comment that a particular answer is no longer relevant to the latest version, version XXX.  Many of our tags are also version-specific.

Comment: Not saying they should be removed. And yes there are tags for specific versions but as I said more often than not the more generic version-less tags are used and you can't add tags to answers.  Plus people like me with not enough reputation can't modify answers to say that the answer is for a specific version. It may surprise some people here but the majority of SO users have no or very little rep so they are unable to contribute by saying "this doesn't work in version X" without adding a new answer (which is actually quite a barrier for a lot of users).

Answer (score 3):

In some cases it makes sense to have a "vote to freeze/archive as history" since you don't want to remove the out of date answer, but you want to show that it is no longer the most relevant (relevant to current release, ...) answer.
The answers, that get frozen/archives, can have a different badge, or background color that is immediately obvious to readers.

Regarding editing/deleting the out of date answers, I don't think that is a good idea. That is rewriting history.

Comment: I like your approach (don't know why people would down vote it). There's already a mechanism to close items, and some are simply no longer relevant today (s.a. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740660/why-does-the-empty-string-not-match-as-seq-empty ).

Answer (score 3):

I just feel the same as the op when I was searching for some answers and get to meta to see what people think about this issue.

I think library version example does not honor the feature request needs.

**TL;DR :**

I think marking questions as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262238/are-there-disadvantages-to-using-a-generic-varchar255-for-all-text-based-field?rq=1) for `Request relevant to date answer` will make questions and answers:

1. Live
2. Dynamic
3. Friction-less dupes
4. Motivates long time users
5. Increase site quality
6. **REALLY** fun

---

**Full details:**

For example, this question :

[Are there disadvantages to using a generic varchar(255) for all text-based fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262238/are-there-disadvantages-to-using-a-generic-varchar255-for-all-text-based-field?rq=1)

This question was answered on 2008 with some great information. It does not reference any library version. It's just a generic question that was relevant for 2008 but it doesn't state anyware if it's relevant on 2014. (won't be better on 2020).

When someone search for answers about TEXT vs VARCHAR on DB, the date answer is very relevant, while does not apply to all questions.
Results show lot of questions with relevant information from different dates and no dupes (which is a great thing!).

And here is where I see a problem (or potential problem). I want to know if that answer is relevant for today (2014) and if not, I want to ask(or answer) for a relevant to date answer.

I don't want to have (ask) a duped question, even with the information about other answers not being relevantes, that will still makes a duped, and will mess things even more. (I see as a no-scalable solution)

The user that answered back then, may be also be relevant to answer it today. There's no way to let him 'review' it.

Last but not least, asking TEXT vs VARCHAR question today is boring for people to answer, because the difficult to know if that was a lazy user or a user that did his homework and really need that dupe.

What the op proposed, and I do as well, is to have a way to mark a question with a 'Request more relevant to date answer'. (not outdated).

When this happens, the question will show up again with clear distinction that it needs more relevant to date answer. Even if the relevant to date answer is still the accepted answer. Because, as a user searching, I don't know if the 2008 answers is still relevant on 2014 (but may be, and it's really interesting). Also it can notify the formed user that has the accepted answer that someone requested for more up to date information.

So he can update the answer with the relevant info, and get accepted again. When someone update an answer with a 'requested for relevant to date answer' can mark itself as a the purpose of edit is to give relevant to date information.

And have another accepted answer, or whatever workflow (I will let this up open since it's irrelevant at this stage)

What I think will it change ?

1. Makes *some* questions more dynamic and live. They can be 'updated' in a organized manner and improves quality over time.
2. Encourages users to look at 'old questions' for relevant updates. I find this quite interesting and I'm sure others will.
3. Have a unified way for users to ask for 'this is the answer I was looking for, but the answers are not clear if it's relevant for today or not'.
4. This *maybe* work for Framework Version library updates.
5. It may brink back long time users to feel effective and motivated (not bored) again.

Comment: As you say, the answer's date is always relevant. (Anyone reading a question or answer should take it into account.) However, if the product is different, it's worth asking a new question for the new version (which won't be a duplicate). You'll never get a system that works based on the answer's date ("*I want to know if that answer is relevant for today (2014) and if not, I want to ask(or answer) for a relevant to date answer.*"), since that system won't know whether you're using today's latest version. You can, in 2014, still be using the 2008 version in production.

Comment: @Bruno shouldn't those answers be in the same question?

Comment: (I hadn't realised that this question existed before answering [this other very similar question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265440/372643).) It depends if there are already answers for multiple versions, but no, I'd say if the software version are sufficiently different, edit the old question to indicate up to which version it applies and ask a new one. By the way, the question you link to does clearly say "*FYI I'm using MySQL 5.*" (presumably 5.0).

Comment: I think the main problem with your suggestion is that you could end up with a number of correct but completely distinct answers on the same question for multiple versions. It might work if you only have one (or maybe two answers) per version, it can become a complete mess if you have three answers for version 1, two answers for version 2, another four for version 3 (...). All these answers could be correct, raising different points, but the Q&A set as a whole would be unreadable.

Comment: Got your points and agree

Answer (score -1):

Last answer/suggestion was 9 years ago.
Imagine how the issue has grown...?

My vote:  Add "Legacy" flag to a question much in the same way we close dupes and opinions, etc.   If 3 contributors of sufficient rep vote the same, the question no longer *appears* unless a "Legacy" box is checked.   *So* many sites scrape SO and now with ChatGPT et. al. (yes....) it is going to get worse.

I am a strong contributor on the mongodb channel and I am irked (polite) by the top search results that read "MongoDB has no transactions", "MongoDB cannot do joins", "MongoDB has no security", etc.   It is 2023.  These issues are at least 7 years behind us.

Comment: [Introducing Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405302/3404097) [tag:outdated-answer]