# How do we handle totally outdated answers?

Tags: support

Have a look to this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955433/how-to-debug-your-jquery-script

The answers are like: "use firebug or insert some code into the js". Nowaday there should be extensions to firebug and chrome which are very better than this solutions. The old answers which got 30 votes and are accepted may prevent the effectiveness of a bounty..

How the community decided to handle this situations?

Comment: I don't think the question is outdated but answers, right?

Comment: @eis: yes, actually fireQuery is a tool for debugging JQuery. Or there is another for chrome, but however the question here can be made more abstract: what to do in all the cases where the answers are outdated?

Comment: IMHO, the outdated answer is okay, provided it's useful and not actively harmful. Well, *in fact*, I still use Firebug to debug web-related. You can just provide the answer if you want, though I may think twice since it seems off-topic (primarily opinion based) now.

Comment: You may consider leaving comment suggesting better approaches and/or add an additional answer

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I think this is the best thing to do.

Answer (score 19):

I've cleaned up the question a bit, it's asking for two things: tools to debug, and methods to debug. It's a nice example of why recommendation questions are not allowed, the outdated answers are those that recommend tools.

I think we should just close the question as a duplicate of [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)
The good answers there explain how to use the built-in developer tools of the various browsers, or have code snippets that can help with debugging.

See [How to deal with hugely upvoted, bad and outdated answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272570/how-to-deal-with-hugely-upvoted-bad-answers) for a discussion on how to handle outdated answers that actually have content instead of recommending a tool.

Comment: (Also related is [this feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272651/introduce-an-obsolete-answer-vote) about how we could improve.)

Comment: "*How to deal with hugely upvoted, bad answers?*" is not necessarily the best place to link to. Outdated and bad answers are not the same thing at all.

Comment: @Bruno the title might be a bit off, the discussion is about outdated answers (or at least that's how it turned out): *"The answer wasn't bad when it was added, but the information is woefully out of date."*

Comment: Nothing is ever completely out of date. It may be out of date for most people, but knowing how something worked in a previous version can often be useful to someone. This discussion starts by confusing the two (bad and outdated), which is never a good sign.

Comment: @Bruno some things are. I'm not talking about versions of software, but say you are asking for security precautions, and previously it was thought X is enough, but since Y has been discovered, now measure Z is relevant as well. Or, some problems were previously unsolvable, but now with modern computing they have been solved, so an answer claiming they are unsolvable is completely out of date.

Comment: @eis, yes, that's fair enough, but leaving an editor's note with a security warning on the answer would be just fine for these cases (and possibly downvote indeed). As for answers that say something's unsolvable, they should be fairly short: even if highly upvoted, another that actually offers a solution should be quite easily visible to the reader.

Answer (score 10):

My general approach to this is written in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265753/372643):

> What someone considers to be an outdated or obsolete answer may not
>   necessarily be outdated for others.
>
> There is a lot of value in keeping track of what the solutions were
>   for past versions of libraries, software, systems, ...
>
> It's not because you're able to run the latest bleeding edge version
>   of the tools you're using that everybody will.
>
> There are such things as legacy systems. Sometimes, you just can't
>   upgrade, or make the choice not to upgrade to prevent other problems
>   (cost, side-effects, ...). (We're all writing today the legacy systems
>   of tomorrow.)
>
> In general, [I'd add a second answer and leave a comment or editor's
>   note on the old answer, without
>   downvoting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265440/372643).

However, what to do may need to be adjusted on a case-by-case basis. This problem is also similar to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265440/372643).

When all the answers are no longer relevant with newer versions of the framework or tools involved, it's probably worth editing the question itself to say "up to version X". Otherwise, leaving a quick editor's note in the answer to mention that some only apply to version X is probably a good idea.

After that, it's up to the reader to make the right move. In general, when reading an answer with a 5-year old timestamp, a good software developer should know that they should dig deeper and read other answers or try to find more recent documentation.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, the stuff that is out of date here are answers responding as a tool recommendation, and those tools may still be relevant answers for some people (IE shouldn't be cleared away).  If you think there are better answers for people discovering this answer now, the best approach is to add a new answer, and label it clearly as a "new thing" that supersedes the older answer.

Here's a recent example where I tried to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16661498/1424361

Because that was a super popular question, the answer is in danger of getting buried a bit, but it still got plenty of votes, and on a less popular question with 1-5 current answers, it shouldn't be too hard for a clearly superior new answer to get noticed, even if it's never marked as accepted.