# Let's allow the answers get elder worthily

Tags: discussion, feature-request, outdated-information

We should make outdated answers to get forgotten form Stack Exchange Sites.

TL;DR

So Stack Overflow is a **priceless** source of information to a lot of It and tech people out there, and **we wanna keep it in this exact same way**.

But when we cover some new and clever tech, that is still and always evolving, we shouldn't be surprised if the answers to any question became *outdated* and create any *confusion*.

To prevent this I would like if Stack Exchange family set some *(first) timeout* to any question, by which it should receive a banner alerting that this answer could be outdated and may need some improvement.

By this time it could get two special flags "Still valid" and "Kinda broken", if it do not receive a certain proportion of confirmation within a *(second) timeout* it should be **forgotten/deleted**.

Just to be a little more specific, a *good proportion* could be two thirds of confirmation from users with at least 2k *carma points*, or something like that.

Also we will need to include some *badges* and *privileges* to promote this renew process with the user base.

Last, but not least, I think that these *timeouts* should be attached to the question tags, and that when a question get lots of tags, the timeout should be the shorter one. The reasoning is as Follow: if a question is tagged with Cobol and Elixir, we would expect that Cobol related technology, tend to evolve a little slower than Elixir *(tendentious remark on my part, I admit!)*, but if we are discussing ways to make Cobol more *versatile* using a young and pulsating technology, and somewhat this tech changes in the near future, any answer related could became useless.

So to the sake of answers aging the shorter timeout should be more appropriate.

Note: Please improve my wording, I will certainly learn a lot by that! ;-)

Comment: What (besides time) makes a  question/answer really outdated? There are many where this actually doesn't apply. This measure would become just unjustified, unless the community judges so.

Comment: I'm tempted to think this is a duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265749/1079354...

Comment: @Makoto That gets pretty close.

Comment: That feels like WAY too much overhead. If a coder somewhere is working off one of my answers and can't be bothered to notice the CLEAR timeframe by my answer and then go "hmmm maybe that's outdated" deserves to get his codebase wrecked by my obsolete code because he's not being careful about his job. (Very blunt point, but my point stands : the onus should be on the user using an answer to check if it makes sense. I don't think it is (or should be) stack's job)

Comment: And, if an answer is outdated, but somewhere someone works with an obsolete library or version (because. If you think this doesn't happen... we have a VERY different experience of the industry), then the outdated answer is just lost to them?

Comment: The pace of change in this industry is misleading... An awful lot of answers simply don't change over time, and those that do often change in such a fundamental way as to **invalidate the question!** For example, implementing Bresenham's line algorithm in C might not've changed much, but the desirability of writing your own line-drawing code has changed greatly over the years. Given folks' penchant for assuming the nature of the answer in their questions, I suspect there are fewer truly *obsolete* answers than anyone realizes.

Comment: Would it instead make sense to have a flag for review? This answer / question is obsolete due to x, y, z. The result of which could be an "obsolete" header. Due to the nature of the flag, I don't think it would cause a huge extra load on the review system either.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98589/automatic-visual-indication-of-old-questions

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, I will try to answer a few ones to the sake of give this idea a chance

Comment: First of all, please read the suggestion carefully: I had suggest that **answers** could get *outdated*, not questions itself, And in that extent it **IS NOT** a DUP of neither of the suplied link, so if you think that you should reconsider your comment (and down vote), please do so kindly, I would appreciate to get others attention in this suggestion.

Comment: @Patrice, you are completely write.
I am, indeed, responsible by any code I submit, to my systems, and I am the sore responsible if something gets wrong.

But when this kind of thing happens, where I should look for any help?

My answer should be StackOverflow(mainly by google), except if you are looking for a Ruby framework that has a quick evolving pace, cause in this case all of the answers are outdated... When I am developing such a solution I tend to avoid StackExchange sites.

To *solve* this I think that SX sites should be able to forget some of them.

Comment: And @Patrice, talking about someone using an outdated lib... Well I think taht, **if enough members** of the Haskel community still use it, they should mark it as "Still valid" and maybe edit it to include against which version it was successfully tested.

Comment: Hey @Shog9, great point, to make it a little more clear, let me suggest an example [Nagios]{https://www.nagios.org/} is a great piece of software that was implement almost entirely in C89, but provide a web interface to control the systems being monitored. **W**el, the interface changes very little details from time to time, and a Lot of internals are pretty solid as well, but looking at their repo, one can see that most of their changes are related to updates in the databases supported, or security fixes. **M**ay they just have questions with the tags **HTML**, **C89**, and many others...

Comment: Continuing to @Shog9 in this case the **C89** tag should be very stable and their questions should get the first timeout by 10 or 15 years, by that time the answer will get some flags pointing if it is really **outdated** or if it is **still valid**;  perhaps any answer would reach the first timeout because of the **HTML** tag, which I think must get a much shorter first timeout, about one or two years at most. And Security ones should be ever shorter, so if the question is about security configuration recommendations , it must get an alert just a few months after it is published.

Comment: Wonderful insight @Knossos, but I thing that alerting who get here only to get an answer that it could need to make a few more research serves this purpose fairly well. Besides that, **Flags**, mostly, **require a review from members of the community with a lot of _carma points_**, so it still exists. Please take a look at my other comments above, and let us know if you think it has any chance of work. Thanks. (PS: pay attention that I am saying only about outdated answers!!)

Comment: @Rafareino to address "who do I turn too when I get an obsolete answer on Stack?" Well you turn to Stack. You ask the question, link to the outdated answer, say that this doesn't help you because it changed. And to address your "if enough members still use it"... What if enough members DON'T, but ONE GUY still does and is looking to get it fixed. Honestly, the way the system works NOW is great. I fail to see the benefit to the community here.... And again, with the extra overhead (a new review queue?) that this'll create, you'd need a GOOD benefit for it... which again, I don't...

Answer (score 4):

This is unacceptable and way too crazy.

For those who still use "outdated" versions, those answers and posts are valuable to them. As they still say: One man's trash is another man's treasure. People should understand that the answer is out-dated in the first place.

First, notice the tags. The tags are usually named after outdated versions of different languages, concepts, etc. Then notice the timestamp which marks the answer for like 5 years old, which is a big red flag the answer is simply outdated. We have deletion criteria for answers and questions so we already have that in place.

But even the answer is 7 years old, maybe someone else wants it. We need no carma(karma?) points to decide, we let the users and system decide. If anyone wants a newer, more up to date answer, post your own question or simply create a bounty stating that you need a more recent answer.

Also, to have badges for deleting random answers and posts which are considered old is not gonna help. That means even more valuable information is going to waste and Stack Overflow isn't going to be more valuable either. Actually, it will get less valuable and that clearly conflicts your view of keeping SO valuable.

Comment: I didn't even think about the crazy stunts people would pull for these extra badges -_-.... good catch there

Comment: You have no idea how many people I have seen hunting for voting badges,,,