# How can we provide a mechanism for showing that a previously correct answer is now obsolete?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It is very possible that an answer might be correct as at the time it was posted.

It would be good to have a formal mechanism for marking answers as obsolete and direction to a more updated or modern answer to the same posed question.

This would be quite helpful for future searchers, as it would save time going through answers which are no longer relevant.

For example:

> Where can I find more information on connection pooling with Dapper.net?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9655870/44080) posted by Mark was correct as at 2012 when posted, but it would seem it no longer holds true (ref: First comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43874607/c-dapper-sql-server-and-connection-pooling)).

**Please note** this request is quite different from:

[What's the policy on down voting previously correct but now outdated answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265749/whats-the-policy-on-down-voting-previously-correct-but-now-outdated-answers)

Comment: If you find an outdated answer and know a more up to date solution, then write a better answer to the question.

Comment: @EthanField Yes, but my point is an updated or more current answer might already exist within SO, for a similar or related question.

Is it not better to have a mechanism for linking to the *now relevant answer*, instead of copying and duplicating existing knowledge within SO?

Comment: That linking mechanism is called a duplicate. You can mark the question as a duplicate of a better, more relevant question.

Comment: @EthanField I'm probably not getting my point across currently, but I understand your point. Thanks.

Comment: Not really a good example, it's a really poor question. I don't really care about the validity of the answer at this point.

Comment: I feel as though I understand your point, but I don't think that something is ever "obsolete". There are plenty of organisations that still use Windows XP or Windows 95 (a great many number of ATMs use old operating systems too). So questions about outdated tech, whilst being about old technology, are still relevant to some.

Comment: Case in point, *Dapper's connection handling* The answer from 2012 was indeed correct at the time. Dapper is a technology that has evolved, the answer no longer holds. @Gimby I *do* care about the validity of the answer as the answer was posted by a highly valued SO user, but i'm now finding conflicting information ...

Comment: @EthanField One scenario where this would be useful, is if a technology was replaced due to security vulnerabilities. In that case, users should be warned to use the more recent (and hopefully safer) technology whenever possible.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong (I've never used Dapper), but is it not possible that there is a single developer in the world using a version of Dapper from 2012? And therefore that this answer may be relevant to them?

Comment: @S.L.Barth True, they should. But in that case, should we start answering all out of date questions with "Don't do this, just update to the newest version where the bug is fixed and the security is better"? There will always be situations where updating is either impossible or impractical for one reason or another, and in those cases historical answers really do help.

Comment: I'm simply saying, if SO can hit a web searcher from 2019 that this answer from 2012 mey no longer hold true for recent version of the technology, for any reason, security, best practice, etc. 

I'm just suggesting that it would be a benefit if SO had a means for pointing such cases out.

Comment: The way to point out such cases is to leave a new answer, link a duplicate, leave a comment. These methods already exist and are successful.

Comment: Imo, edit the old version answer to add information to specify what version this answer is correct.  Link the question to the new question with uptodate answer.

Comment: [One of the most upvoted answers in the history of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/4528269) is an answer that has been edited a number of times whenever the technology has changed, but it has not removed the outdated information, as this is still relevant to users with dated versions of the software.

Comment: "should we start answering all out of date questions?"

 well, if SO was offering a points incentive for such an effort, and there was a clear mechanism in place for this *Audit*, people just might take the time to pitch in and help. It does not take anything away from the previous posts, they are there for historical reference as pointed out.

Comment: How would you have users answer outdated questions? Take, for example, a question about some weird bug that occurred in an old version of a programming language (Java, C, Python, take your pick), if this bug had a solution that allowed you to workaround it in the historical version of the language but was fixed in a later version, what would you advise the OP?

Comment: No, the OP is not the beneficiary of this suggestion i'm making. The OP got his answer way back in 2012 and expressed his acceptance of said answer as it solved his problem then. I'm suggesting this for future users of SO, who find a similar problem today, but may be unaware that the proposed answer is no longer valid. If SO could point that out to future users and guide them to an appropriate answer, that would be invaluable.

Comment: As I've stated, you can add a new answer, link to a new duplicate or add a comment to explain that the answer is outdated/irrelevant/fixed in a new update/a security flaw. All of those solutions work to do exactly as you are describing. They direct the new user to a *potentially* more useful answer.

Comment: seems a previous effort is here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272651/introduce-an-obsolete-answer-vote