# Moderator overreach or business as usual?

Tags: discussion, moderators, deleted-comments

The case goes like this.

- A four year old node.js answer of mine is outdated. Quite possibly related to the fact that it is about node.js and four years old.
- A user approaches me in a comment: *"`createCipher` is dangerous and deprecated, this answer should not be used in 2020."*. At 190,000+ reputation we can assume the user has both lots of experience with the site itself *and* expertise in the question topic at hand. That user also is a moderator.
- I invite the mod to provide a better alternative, because I have not been following along the changes in node.js libraries very much over the last four years and they and obviously know about something that makes the code in this answer dangerous. Everybody being able to contribute important information or corrections even to old content is a *fundamental* feature of Stack Overflow. It's at the heart of what makes this site so useful.
- Instead the mod downvotes my answer and walks away. (Nobody has interacted with that answer for four years, and then a comment and a downvote happen in a matter minutes. So, yes, the mod did it. There was nobody else around.)

So far, this is a common scheme. Some random person holds out a stick for you to jump over, and when you don't comply immediately, they downvote you, because you've had it coming. I think most people have seen that happen one way or another. The -1 doesn't bother me, and the answer is still at +13, I could shrug and move on.

Then again, it's not a particularly great way to interact with other people, and it does precisely nothing to improve the content on the site, so I would expect more of a balanced approach from a mod.

And now the conclusion:

- I ask the mod if they are being serious with pulling off this kind of poor interaction.
- The mod does not seem to like being called out and deletes my comment.

And here is where I draw the line.

Mods are regular users of the site, and if they think doing that "you jump when I tell you" thing is fine, they are free to do this. I would expect better, but it's how the site works, so no argument there.

But mods also hold couple of unique powers, such as deleting comments without any kind oversight, and I don't think they should use them to silently rid themselves of somebody who mildly inconveniences them while they do it. Nobody else gets to.

So the question is, was this supposed to go this way?

Comment: I guess that mod never got your comment as you didn't @-reply them. For a user with 281k we can assume they know how comment replies work.

Comment: Comment replies work without explicitly having to @ someone. And typically comments don't go away on their own, so there's ample evidence that the mod saw the reply.

Comment: That is only true if only two users have commented. Not the case on that comment thread.

Comment: It's also true of immediately consecutive replies.

Comment: Define "immediate", with a few seconds? if it's that quick, it's unlikely the comment would be directed at the previous commenter, or they had read it. More than 1 person in the comments, you need to @ them.

Comment: No, *consecutive*, as in "I write to a comment thread, the last person in the thread gets notified". Not the case?

Comment: No, that's not the case. That's [not how pinging works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Comment: Interesting, so you did not get notified of this very comment here?

Comment: "Some random person holds out a stick for you to jump over" "doing that "you jump when I tell you" thing" - what is it that you believe the moderator was trying to coerce you into doing?

Comment: *"No, consecutive, as in "I write to a comment thread, the last person in the thread gets notified". Not the case? "* I was not pinged about that comment, no. You didn't @ me and more than one person is in the comments. No @, no ping.

Comment: Note, you (Tomalak) will get notified, as you are the OP of the topic, who will get pinged about *all* comments on the post, regardless of if they are aimed at you or not.

Comment: @lamu That's good to know, I had that wrong all the time.

Comment: You also have to spell someone's name correctly to ping them: `Larnu`, not `Lamu`. ;)

Comment: Downvoting an outdated answer is exactly what downvotes are made for. They mark things that aren't useful anymore. That part is definitely not a poor interaction but an exemplary one. Deleting comments without telling you why, especially after you seems to have asked for clarification may be a bit poor, but only if you were not on the more angry side yourself.

Comment: @Trilarion The original comment and the response [were not deleted](https://imgur.com/a/ejXEJfY). Only the next one, which was (according to its author description), much noisier. Deleting comments is always done without explanation.

Comment: { 2020-01-20 18:26:45Z DW }, 
{ 2020-01-20 18:27:11Z  Comment}

The Timeline show that there is no pressure by comment that was followed in a downvote. 
If those 2 elements are related. Mods are users too, I think we should not weight the diamond too mutch, when they are doing normal interaction. 

I would not like to have them get a sock puppet in order to not have every interaction spoiled by this group of pixels.

Comment: Imo it's just a downvote for quality/security concern, and a comment to indicate the issue. That's cool that you ask for clarification and cleanner code. And that you want to maintain an old answer of yours. Time passes and answers might grow old or obsolote. Asker has no obligation to maintain. That's why vote, comment, or/and answer are the correct way to address old answer.

Comment: @Tomalak: I checked, and the moderator was *not* notified of your comment (we can see the list of comment responses a user receives). So your assertion that they would have received your comment response because it was consecutive is not correct.

Comment: @Martijn Okay, then I clearly overreacted on this one. Point taken.

Comment: I've pinged them on this in the mod chatroom, so they should be aware about your response now.

Comment: @xdtTransform The situation being: old thread, only answer, answer used to be correct/good, answer is now deprecated (but not wrong per se), somebody knowledgeable sees it. Will casting a downvote make things better? How is this "handling" anyrhing?

Comment: @Tomalak: well, voting is personal and in aggregate confers a score about the usefulness and applicability of answers. You also got feedback on the post that it is no longer as good as it once was, and the dv gave it more weight than just the comment. Had you had the know-how to update the answer today, you would have done, but the voter and / or commenter can't know you haven't been keeping up to date. Please don't start arguing about voting now, I'd hope that you have enough experience with SO that you understand that this system has done a great job in general.

Comment: Anyone now visiting that answer and *still downvoting it*: I've already updated it to not use the deprecated method (which didn't use an IV) to the current recommended method. The answer is back on solid AES symmetric encryption ground and won't leak info if the first 16 bytes of plaintext were to repeat across multiple messages.

Comment: Err, yes, i downvoted your answer, because while I'm a moderator, I'm still a regular user, and I have a right to downvote things. I then left a comment *with* my downvote, so you would understand *why*. I didn't think either of these things were problematic.

Comment: What we learn from this is that we're indeed better off not commenting after placing a downvote.

Comment: @meagar You can downvote anything you deem downvote-worthy, no argument there. A constructive feedback, *especially* when it's about a minefield such as encryption, would have been so much better, especially when you know the topic better than the answer author. I'm always glad when people point out stuff in my answers, but *"[...] is dangerous and deprecated" + downvote*  is not exactly improving things. What should I have done? Sit down 3 hours, catch up with the API changes in a node module I never use, and try to craft an update to code I did not even write in the first place? :|

Comment: @Tomalak Downvotes are as much a signal for people finding answers via Google, as they are a feedback mechanism for the author. This is exactly how I came across it. Ideally, I would have deleted your answer, or put a huge "THIS ANSWER IS DANGEROUS" in flashing marque across the top, but SO doesn't really support that kind of feedback, and **I was at work at my actual day job that pays me**, searching for a node symmetric encryption library. I didn't have time to either edit your question or monitor the comments for your response. I downvoted, commented, then went back to work.

Comment: The vote and the comment are not signals solely for the post author, if at all. The vote affects the score, and that's a signal for all future users. The comment is information for all future users that read an outdated answer. Both are perfectly good, useful feedback; and **either** is much better than no feedback at all. The post author, specifically, is not obligated to do anything else. They can, if they are willing and have the means. Or someone else's can. But if someone can't, for whatever reason, fully edit your question, doesn't mean that other feedback is not "improving things".

Comment: My tl;dr is - You are too busy to edit your answer into a correct state? Well so am I!

Comment: Arguably *all* of my old answer are, well, old. It stands to reason that quite a few contain outdated approaches, deprecated method calls, or things that are no longer considered good practice for any number of reasons. Do you keep tabs on all of your old answers?

Comment: Nobody is telling you that you should. I don't know how you came to that.

Comment: @Tomalak I do keep tab on my old answers... by using the exact input you complain here - votes on *an old answer* indicate that *question* is useful/active, negative votes mean it worth checking answer again for correctness/freshness, extra positive votes - check if small improvement can move the answer to the top in given question. But I don't have too many answers which makes it easy...

Comment: And here is a link to a policy on such obsolete questions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265749/whats-the-policy-on-down-voting-previously-correct-but-now-outdated-answers...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A bunch of things here, to clarify.

First, yes, I downvoted your answer, because it's dangerous and uses a method deprecated for security reasons. It's also the first answer that comes up when you google "Node Symmetric encryption", which is hugely problematic, but I digress.

Then, I left a comment explaining why I downvoted your answer.

I hope we can agree so far, at 190,000 and 281,000 rep each, that there really isn't much wrong with my actions so far.

Then, you left a comment shortly after:

> Thanks for the heads-up. Since this is the accepted answer (i.e. I can't remove it) and I haven't been following along with changes to the crypto module, could you suggest an edit that contains safer code?

You didn't ping me, so I didn't *see* this comment, until you left a follow-up comment, **three hours later**:

> @meagar Seriously? :D

Then, I saw both comments. I had no idea what "Seriously?" meant, because I found it very hard to think that a 281,000 rep user would find it at all surprising that they had received a downvote.

I replied

> Seriously what?

And then **again I never got your response**...

> Seriously downvote? I mean, really?

Because **again you didn't ping me**. At 281,000 reputation you *really* should know how comments work by now.

So, returning to your answer sometime later, I saw *zero* response from you, but noticed through the moderator tools that there was a new deleted comment. Another moderator had deleted your "Seriously downvote?" comment, because that comment is the definition of noise and is off topic. Again, you should know this.

Finally, seeing that the **actual** comment your "seriously" comment chain was leading to was deleted, I cleaned up my own "seriously what?" and your original "seriously?", because they had been read by their intended recipients, they were off topic, and they served no useful purpose now that the culmination of the back-and-forth had been deleted.

That was my last interaction with your question or comments until this morning, when I woke up to this meta question, and the now deleted comment below your original question, where you incorrectly assume a **lot** about what has transpired:

> @meagar ...and now you have removed my comments? Are you really sure how moderation on this site is supposed to work and that you are doing a good job at it?

I have only one question for you: Seriously?

Comment: I feel the need to say that I'm leaving SO to do my *real* job for a few hours, and I hope any delay in my response won't be taken as mod-abuse. (This comment will hopefully be taken in the tongue-in-cheek spirit in which it was written).

Comment: Well, yes. I should know how comments work. I was firmly believing that the comment after would ping the comment before it, and that the @ is not strictly necessary. I don't usually take part in complex discussions via the comments, so I often leave off the @ and things still work out, so the system appeared to work as I thought it would. That last comment I made as (admittedly) in spite, and I'm sorry for it.

Answer (score 16):

Briefly:

- You suspect a moderator downvoted you (but as always with voting, you do not know if that's actually the case; the mod saw your answer, someone else might as well, **particularly since the question was edited 8hrs ago**, which bumped it in the "Active questions" list).
- You ask the moderator to explain why they downvoted you
- Your comment demanding an explanation was deleted

There is no overreach there. Comments asking for vote justifications are routinely deleted.

It's fine if the same mod you presume downvoted the answer deleted it, or some other mod did.

It's fine if they deleted it in response to a flag, or just because they saw the comment. Those comments are **noise** and we are better off if they are deleted on sight.

Personally, I flag them every single time I see them. I'd be disappointed if those flags were declined.

---

I am focusing on the comment deletion, since that's the only action that's thing that could be characterized as "moderator powers abuse".

Voting (up or down), is not a moderator power, and every user is free to vote as their please as long as they are not committing some form of voting fraud.

*If* the mod voted on your answer, it is entirely within their rights as a user. Moderators, after all, are just users with some additional privileges.

Comment: *"You ask the moderator to explain why they downvoted you"* No, I did not. Not with a word. (My entire post above shows that I *know* the reason for the downvote.)

Comment: "Your comment demanding an explanation" There was no comment demanding an explanation.

Comment: _"I ask the mod if they are being serious with pulling off this kind of poor interaction._". What is that if not asking them to justify their (presumed) vote? What does "interaction" mean in this context?

Comment: That was not a quote of what I wrote. The point is, as a moderator *and* somebody who has more current information on something (especially something that is inherently dangerous like outdated code dealing with encryption) - is it better to contribute, or to retaliate because the other person does not jump when you feel they should? I asked them in good faith to point out a better alternative first, mind you.

Comment: I can only go with whatever you provide. If the text is not accurate, please update the question with a more representative one. And your first comment has not been deleted. Only the other one, where you ask about this "interaction" has. The second comment was seen as not needed. Maybe flagged and deleted. Considering how you describe the content of that comment, I think it is appropriate.

Comment: Nothing is flagged and deleted in a matter of minutes in a question that is 4 years old and has not seen *any* interaction whatsoever since it was answered.

Comment: That's false. I flag things and they get deleted in a matter of minutes all the time. But even if it wasn't flagged, if the comment followed the lines you describe in the question, it was correctly deleted by the mod. They do not need to wait on flag to act.

Comment: @Tomalak I think a lot of comment flags are handled automatically (and therefore instantly) - if the comment is flagged and matches certain patterns it's just deleted so I don't think the speed of it is too unusually

Comment: Since voting or commenting does not push a thread onto the homepage, the number of people casually seeing and flagging a stray comment in an ancient thread can be put very close to zero. But I guess the discussion is moot by now, or always has been.

Comment: @Tomalak The question was edited. And never mind that, the Q&A is obviously found now and then. You've got the upvotes to prove it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure mods have the same vote limits as everyone else, they can just do unlimited reviews / close / delete votes etc.

Comment: @Peter You are probably right. I just thought they had all the rate-limits removed.

Comment: @yivi For the record, the question was edited on Dec 8 '16 at 16:42 (initial post), and the next time today 20 minutes ago by Martijn Pieters. No edits happened in between.

Comment: You mean the **answer**. The **question** was edited 11 hours ago.

Comment: You're right. That would have pushed the thread to the front page for a bit.

Comment: @Tomalak it feels like a lot of your argumentative rests on the 'it was an old question with no activity'. But editing a question makes it active, kicks it back up the queue. It's normal when these things happen that the question attracts some eyeballs. And with these eyeballs, moderation is to be expected. Honestly if your only argument is 'it all happened too fast'.... I...... Don't think that's much to stand on :/. All in all, voting is personal. No one *has* to correct errors they see. Your answer contains a dangerous practice. Someone didn't wanna propagate said practice. Simple.

Comment: @Patrice You're right, I might have jumped to a few conclusions, based on how the everything went down from my point of view at the time. Discussing it here gave me the some perspective, but by now I much rather hadn't started the thread at all. :) Oh well. And again, I wasn't upset by the downvote itself, at all. But downvoting a reasonably well-voted answer does nothing to improve it. I was upset that it happened as (what I perceived as) the reaction to my thanks and request for a better solution.

Comment: @Tomalak a lot of users simply ignore such comments not accompanied by downvote. A lot of users are not there at all (whether they show up as "recently seen" or not) to act on just comment. Downvoting answer that one considers bad is responsible moderation action - it makes recipient more likely to actually act (sometimes acts out :) ) and more importantly ranks the answer. It looks like it worked in your case as designed. And yes highly upvoted obsolete answers are problem but so far the only tool to deal with them is downvote (feel free to suggest better alternative... also plenty tried)

Answer (score 5):

> you jump when I tell you

*Every* user is allowed to downvote an answer they don't deem helpful, and especially in the security-related field, there's loads of dangerous stuff going around on the site, and being copy-pasted all over the place, and used by people in production.

I for one am definitely not a security expert. I will not be handing out advice on how users should encrypt their data and where they should store their secret keys and how long tokens should be valid and whatnot. I *do* know enough about the subject though to recognize bad practices and dangerous advice.

When I see a post that's spreading dangerous advice, I downvote and comment. Do I have a solution? Probably not. Should that prevent me from voting and commenting? No. What *do* I want to see then? I don't know. Maybe they should do some more research and edit their post, or they should just delete it altogether. Because seriously, "the output looks random to me, so it must be secure" seems to be the general criterion by which such user assess their security code.

So it's pretty much possible that the mod in question recognized a security flaw in your answer, *without* knowing the solution to it. They were not telling you to jump, they were telling you that there was a hole ahead.

The fact that a moderator did these actions to one of your posts, which I as a regular user also would do, changes nothing about that.

When you started discussing with them instead of following up on their advice, you granted them the possibility to remove the off-topic comments, and so that happened.

Comment: *"Every user is allowed to downvote an answer they don't deem helpful,"* Absolutely. I said so myself.

Comment: In my answer I try to convey that the mod maybe didn't have the solution to the problems that your answer presented. A mod can say, just like any other user, "this answer is [dangerous|incorrect|outdated]"  withouth explaining how to change the answer so it is no longer that. That's a whole different question from a mod deleting a discussion that is not going anywhere.

Comment: "Maybe they should do some more research and edit their post, or they should just delete it altogether." - I can't delete it, it's the accepted answer. I even reacted with *"Since this is the accepted answer (i.e. I can't remove it) ..."*, which goes to show that I was prepared to remove it if necessary.

Comment: _"I was prepared to remove it if necessary"_ - _"the answer is still at +13, I could shrug and move on"_ - or were you? But this answer is supposed to answer the more general case what one could do in such a scenario. You appear to be  admandant that the moderator abused their powers, and I disagree.

Comment: Of course I was. I wrote the comment requesting some clarification way before this meta post. I could have shrugged and moved on, and I *didn't*.