# Yet another offensive email from another new user on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette, offensive, harassment

So, I previously had asked [a similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261941/what-do-i-do-about-receiving-an-offensive-email-from-another-user-on-stack-overf) regarding a harassing and offensive email I received from an S.O. user who didn't like to have high-quality posts! S.O. team was very helpful and they suspended that user account from all S.E. websites; however it seems that it's not the happy end of the story!

I edited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200791/facebook-cordova-plugin-ios#25200791) post today, and an hour later I received an email, saying:

> Do you have nothing better to do than correct grammar on Stack Overflow?
>   Your website runs at snails pace and looks utterly horrible. 
>   Maybe work on your coding rather than fishing for points on Stack Overflow.

Again, no actual need to defend myself, but we know that there are no points being fished for editing posts after 2k rep (where you won't suggest the edits, but just do them), and the user hasn't even noticed that it's not a *grammar* fix, but punctuation, formatting and capitalization.

[image]

We can also see the comment below the reverted post saying:

[image]

I know one solution is removing all personal stuff off my profile, which is only a link to my website which allows some users to stalk down into it, browse it, and discover my email address to send these emails; but isn't it actually good to spot these users and be more alert towards them? I'm wondering if we have a missing "Report user" button somewhere, maybe?

The reason I'm mentioning this, is that I see [various](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267851/what-do-i-do-about-being-harassed-by-users-outside-of-stack-overflow) [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261178/what-do-you-do-when-someone-calls-you-personally-about-an-answer) similar posts here that have ended up in deleting their personal information to avoid these issues. I don't disagree that it's a solution, but in that case, that comment without the direct mention of my username, would've remained there forever, reproducing rude, new users, and not being constructive or educative to them at all.

On the other hand, I know that adding a "Report user" button isn't a great idea either, and it only increases the chore load for moderators here, but should we keep sending emails to S.O. team to moderate these offensive users who think having high-quality posts will make S.O. a horrible place, and their number seems to be increasing recently?

Edit: Oh! Same story again! I received down-votes right after all this, as well (Let's see if they'll be detected as serialized ones :-/):

[image]

(And the down-votes are to be continued as I'm editing this post now...)

Comment: Wouldn't this be classed as a (partial) feature request?

Comment: Yeah @Sam. I wasn't quite sure, so I didn't mess around with the tags. I can add it though if the folks agree. (:

Comment: I know this isn't a desirable solution, but unless you get a decent amount of legitimate / useful emails, consider removing your email for your website for the time being. Unfortunately, people suck.

Comment: "Stop making Stack Overflow a horrible place" deserves an offensive flag in its own right. Flagged as such and urge others to do the same.

Comment: Maybe another solution could be - *Show complete profile to people who have been on SO for atleast some time (a week or two?. Not based on rep). Usually people who send such spam mails are new users. A week in SO, and you will know how it works. The `report user` button  allows you to report only after* you get the mail.

Comment: Other than tell you to bin the email (this is just spam, really) and ignore them, there isn't much we can do other than become a vigilante mob and harass the user back. I don't think that's constructive either. If the user *continues* to be abusive, flag the *post*, using *other* let the moderator team know about the user's abusive behaviour and let them take care of this.

Comment: Moderators can only handle what abusive behavior a user engages in within the site. It's still best to defer to the staff for everything else.

Comment: @BoltClock: in which case forwarding the email to staff at stackexchange dot com is the better option here?

Comment: I have flagged your rude/offensive comments (where you comment on new users for edit) for mods and got those deleted and also your [backtick](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25134707/revisions) [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25135114/revisions) [sprees](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25136171/revisions). But yes, offensive emails are totally unacceptable. Users should use flags and resolve as per site rules, if they don't agree with your edits.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion: Those are **not vandalizing editing sprees**. Please don't characterise formatting edits as such. You appear to have wholly different standards from most editors on the site.

Comment: @BoltClock, well I could argue it was being offensive towards the principles of intelligent behavior.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion: those edits happen to be a *valid use of backticks*.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion, those are cases where backticks are not perhaps necessary but they're still just fine (used for type names, for example). Backticking sprees are more problematic when they include `words` that shouldn't be backticked or if they're used as rep-farms while leaving actual problems behind (and you don't get any edit rep after 2K).

Comment: @BoltClock I think my flagging history will be visible to you, please check in recent helpful flags. It `makes` code `very` difficult `to` read. Also, I have read multiple mails on Meta where general concensus is the same. Anyways, it's about offensive mails, so I was just saying that if someone has objection to edits, they should use flags and get a rollback or something, mails are not good. Seems my comment upset everybody, you can delete my comment. Also check the [nice comment from OP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25165409/2982225) which was deleted as rude/offensive.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but please vote the linked question based on its own merits only, not based on whether you find the user's behavior to be disagreeable or not.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: apparently Meta has become a vigilante mob, if you look at the downvotes this guy's old questions have gotten since this was posted. I strongly disagreed with the "community has an attitude problem" post, but now I'm not so sure. This behavior by meta denizens is disappointing. Judge the content, don't target the user. (Note to reader: I say this as someone who has probably downvoted **a lot** more stuff than you.)

Comment: @kviiri that's the meta effect. It isn't a good question.

Comment: @Joe, I know. I'm just reminding people to downvote it for the right reasons.

Comment: I respect you a lot @MartijnPieters and your opinions too. I will certainly recheck and _if valid,_ wont't flag such editing endeavours. I only replied to BoltClock because he is the only person who can see the entire picture. And also, I was saying that people should use flags, and condemning offensive mails. But then...I upset everybody it seems.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion The only thing you could say that was "wrong" with those edits (only 2 of them) was "fluff" which should have been removed, was missed. Even then, they're all still perfectly legitimate.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion: yes, there are those that abuse backticks and don't understand what they are for. I see no evidence for that here however, the backticks are used purely to mark up identifiers and keywords, which is what they are meant for. They make the post more legible (in my opinion).

Comment: @Wooble: I have seen this disappointing behaviour time and again when a Meta post calls out bad behaviour of a specific user; hence my remark that posting this on Meta is perhaps not the best place for it. Not everyone can focus on just the content, and leave emotion out of the equation. I can see *in this case* sort-of why it is happening; the user in question is behaving appallingly, but still.

Comment: @Sam Yes, I agree it's human error by me and all the mods who handled all the flags on the user in question. I won't flag good edits and beautiful rude comments anymore...we should never judge a picture only by seeing half of it. Anyways as I said, if anyone has issues, flagging is appropiate, offensive mails are condemnable.

Comment: @SList - Moderators have no ability to change votes, nor do you want us to. While I really hate the Meta pile-ons I've seen over the years (such as this), unless there's outright fraud involved, or targeted voting from one individual to another, there's nothing to do.

Comment: @Neeku If the emails come from the same place or have some header information in common; perhaps you could at least avoid having to see them by adding a mail filter of some sort?

Comment: This thread is a poster child for three challenges SO faces: knee-jerk reactions to a single downvote, knee-jerk reactions to 'tidy-up' edits, and revenge-voting.

Comment: @thelostmind That does sound like a helpful precaution to implement. Though, in this particular case, the offending user has been registered on SO for over 4 years so it would not have prevented this. It might be overkill, but a more effective (though still imperfect) approach would be if users could choose thresholds a user must meet to view their complete profile details such as *duration a user has been registered on SE/specific network*, *amount of rep on network*.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion The consensus on meta is that backticks should be used **only** for nouns referring to keywords/identifiers in the language in question. They should not be used for emphasis on random words which are not elements of the code. This is your misinterpretation of the consensus in failing to distinguish between these two scenarios. If you mention the class named `ProductsController` or the data type `string` then it is appropriate to backtick these, but isn't strictly enforced.  The bigger issue is the misuse of backticks. That doesn't appear to be the case in the items you link.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The on-site issues were the serial down-votes and the rudeness in the comments.

The votes have been invalidated and the user contacted about these and the rudeness.

If they do it again flag one of your posts for moderator attention and we'll take things to the next level (which may well involve suspension).

However, unfortunately we can't stop them contacting you off-site.

Comment: This answer deserves more up-votes that the current quantity. +15 for this answer while -35 for the one below, and that means we have more than twice down-voters than up-voters. Anyhow, thank you for your attention and your response Chris. I also won't manage ignoring the humorous edit summary by @Jongware

Answer (score -180):

There was absolutely NO NEED for an edit. I specifically had the naked link in there so people would recognise the repo in question without having to click on it.

What you did was absolutely pointless and a waste of time for everyone involved. 
The question itself is clear, capitalisation of the letter 'i' does not make the question any more clear.

I sent you the email because I couldn't contact you directly on this. 
It's not stalking, you're on the internet. Why not invest time on helping people rather than making their lives more miserable. I got a negative on the question after your correction so I assumed it was you.

Comment: "I couldn't contact you directly on this" - you can @-reply to everyone in the revision history of a post. And if you care that much about a small edit to your question that you invest the time to even go looking for a mail address of the editor, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: guess I wasn't the only one. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261941/what-do-i-do-about-receiving-an-offensive-email-from-another-user-on-stack-overf

Comment: He's not only doing it wrong, he's wasting more time than the edit took just to rant about the edit ... good example when saying not to waste time.

Comment: Your question is **not just there for you**. Stack Overflow is a place to curate programming knowledge, and your post, if of good enough quality, has the potential to remain there *for years*. As such we edit posts for grammar and formatting. If this is a problem for you, then *Stack Overflow is not a site for you*.

Comment: Even if the edit had been bad, and even if you *couldn't* have communicated via a comment, there is *no* excuse for that sort of email. And just because someone else has also been rude doesn't excuse you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters to be fair, the initial author should always have the final say on how the edits turn out. Most askers are grateful for edits, because they often agree it improves their posts (especially in questions), but they shouldn't be prevented from rolling it back if they wish (this is similar to [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268074/372643)): we can still downvote or vote to close in this case. This being said, what Jon Skeet says is absolutely right: there's no excuse for offensive e-mails like this.

Comment: @Bruno: Absolutely, the behaviour is inexcusable. As for rolling back grammar and spelling edits, what will happen is that others will come around and *also* try to apply the edits again, because that is how the site works. I recently came across someone who had 'social-political views' on using lowercase *i* instead of *I* in their posts and had a hard time keeping people from editing their posts. Better to inform such users that they might be fighting a losing battle here and reconsider posting here if this is so fundamental to their identity.

Comment: Rolling back an edit that you disagree with on a post of your own does not involve e-mailing the user making the edit.

Comment: Yes, there's need for edits when we find grammar, spelling and formatting problems in someone's post. These are *improvements* and should be taken as a learning opportunity. You're welcome ;)

Comment: I've deleted my initial question as its become a domain for abuse and negative votes. While I understand grammatical corrections are part of any public forum, I still stand that the corrections made were not relevant. Which is why I reverted the edit BUT it was edited again? The down vote was unjustified. Stack Overflow has become very elitist over the years, monopoly of votes and ego boasts.

Comment: @Neo This question is *not* about the edits, really. You can argue whether the edit was appropriate or not (I think it was), but that's not what you did here: You went and harassed someone off-site.

Comment: Maybe we should start banning people for what they do off-site all the time then !

Comment: It is wrong to write such offensive emails. Nothing justifies rudeness as Jon Skeet said. If anything seems inappropiate on the site, please use flags, mods will handle the flags and remediate the issue. They are very helpful. The site provides all the proper tools - rollback, comment with @, flag.

Comment: @Neo: If someone's behaviour off-site is directly and provably related to their on-site behaviour, I'd be fine with a ban in that situation. If a user decided to email abuse to everyone who edited their posts, then a ban would be entirely warranted, IMO.

Comment: It is not to everyone though. I've received a herd of negative down votes on my legacy posts. Then i've also been paraded with edit's on my legacy posts. Topped it all off with a Ban. Behaviour off site is behaviour off the site, it is not connected to Stack Overflow.

Comment: As author of your posts, you can rollback every edit which you dont agree with. Click on "edited xyz mintes ago" on any post. The entire revision history will open for that post. On any previous version, click rollback. Simple.

Comment: Sorry for the downvotes, I disagree with the downvotes, but vigilantes become emotional and start upvoting/downvoting. Its known as meta effect. Some times it goes to such extent that mods have to lock posts to prevent voting. And as for the ban, as Jon Skeet said, it is related to SO, so ban is valid. You should have used on-site tools to remediate the edit. Thats the crux of the argument. You shouldn't write emails off-site. After the ban time expires, please never repeat such things again.

Comment: Chris wrote in his answer that you would be "suspended" _if you repeat_ the behaviour. So on that basis ban should mean that there was repetition.

Comment: I did down vote her question on this page as I don't agree with it. I only saw Chris's post after.

Comment: On this page, its good to downvote to show disagreement. Thats what downvotes are for on Meta site. That is not offensive. But Chris wrote suspension will occur "if they do it again, we will take it to the next level".

Comment: Your profile doesn't show the banner which is displayed for suspended users. Are you sure that you have been banned?

Comment: @Infinite, it might be a question ban (there is no banner for these), given the flak this user's questions are currently taking. There are also pity upvotes that may reverse this. What a mess.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes, that explains the absence of the banner. Meta effect is indeed messy.

Comment: The one part of this that I agree with is the part about the bare URL. If you are going to replace a bare URL with arbitrary text, the least you could do is make the text descriptive. [this] is no better than [here], but far, far worse than [github.com/.../phonegap-facebook-plugin].

Comment: @Neo The fact that you were so angered that you felt the need to contact the user off-site, and to *keep* harassing them afterwards, suggests that perhaps you are identifying too closely with the issue here. You may wish to sit and reflect on your unusually high defensiveness and unusually strong reaction to these events; not so much to help your time on SO, but more to help you become a better person in general, as I suspect these attitudes may extend to other areas of your life. General happiness will improve after reflection.

Comment: @BoltClock I agree. If I were making the edits, I would have edited the link to be [Apache Cordova Facebook Plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin), since it looks better than `https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin` and `this`.

Comment: I would have done the same as Cupcake, but what should have happened is the post then edited again to address that issue, not completely rolled back and the whole offsite email stuff

Comment: "*I got a negative on the question after your correction so I assumed it was you.*" I would like to point out that editing a post *bumps it* in the list of questions, so *anyone* could have seen your question after it was edited, and then decide to downvote it. You *cannot* assume that it was actually Neeku here who ended up downvoting it, even if it was right after she edited it, because that could legitimately be someone else.

Comment: As @Cupcake mentioned, the edit bumps up the questions to the front page of all users following the tag. Incomplete edits coupled with rude remarks scolding new users for not formatting properly makes these posts downvote magnets on the tag. It's not just your post, happens to all the posts that are edited without addressing all the issues in the posts. We come to answer the posts and after seeing all the mess, we leave. Possibly those who open the question after the bump - cast the downvote. Never make assumptions about who downvoted.

Comment: "I got a negative on the question after your correction so I assumed it was you." -- I beg you to reconsider that line of thought. If someone just decides to dedicate some of his/her time to improve content on the site, what sense does it make to downvote it afterwards? Furthermore, I personally often rush to the "edit" button when I see typos/bad formatting **in order to prevent the authors from being downvoted**. Bad grammar/formatting (including lowercase "i"s) are often seen as a lack of effort from the author's part, and tend to gather a higher rate of downvotes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You said _"...'social-political views' on using lowercase i "_. Can you explain their reasons? I'm just curious!!!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: I don't think that serves any purpose; I deliberately did not link to the account, repeating their thinking here doesn't add anything to this debate.

Comment: @Neo I completely disagree with you but I'm sad to see many of your questions/answers have been downvoted...with a quick look I really don't see any reason for downvotes. As you see we're all pretty childish.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, it's off topic on this thread but I was TOO curious! Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: The Meta effect at play. Since reputation is a measurement of trust, some people try to express their opinion that a user has lost community trust, by downvoting posts. I don't condone that behaviour, I prefer to judge content for the content alone, but the behaviour is not necessarily childish.

Comment: @MartijnPieters of course I _understand_ motivations behind that but - as you said - posts _should_ be voted according to their content. If it's not childish (wrong word, maybe) at least it's not productive for SO itself (because a worse post may have higher votes because an author is _rude_). Well anyway it can be classified as "by design" with meta...