# What would the consequence for insulting someone be?

Tags: discussion, rules, rude-or-abusive

Let's say person A posted something then person B came along and insulted person A.

- What **exactly** would happen to person B as a consequence?
- Would they be suspended and / or get points taken away?
- What would happen if person B was insulting person A because person A had insulted them first?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

Comment: see also: [Why do comment flags sometimes take immediate effect?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266161/839601)

Comment: FWIW, I'd like to avoid framing things in terms of "punishment". This isn't kindergarten, and we're not particularly interested in *people*, but in content. Content which doesn't fit gets removed. People who steadily produce such content will be prevented from doing so. That is all.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for the input, appreciate it.

Comment: *Btw are people downvoting because this is a dup* @code11 - I didn't vote but FWIW, I didn't find the post I was thinking of when I searched for a dupe. (I assume it's been deleted.) Most posts on rude comments are asking why the flag was declined.

Comment: @BSMP Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: Since question seem to be asking for a list - e-mail stalking is one option - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268123/yet-another-offensive-email-from-another-new-user-on-stack-overflow/268132

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no rigid requirement; moderators are free to use their own discretion, to a certain extent, in determining what action is merited in such a situation.

The comments would be deleted no matter what.  In most situations, that's likely to be the end of it.  If the content is *particularly* problematic, if there's a pattern over time, etc. then other actions may be taken, such as a written warning to the user that will remain visible to other moderators on the user's profile going forward, up to potentially even an account suspension (the time period would vary radically based on the specifics of the situation).

As to being provoked, a moderator is of course able to take such factors into consideration when determining the appropriate action, but do note that, "they insulted me first" does not excuse you also acting inappropriately.  A single provoked outburst in a stressful situation is rather unlikely to result in something like an account suspension, but if you make a habit of posting inappropriate comments you're likely to find yourself facing some serious consequences, even if other people are also posting inappropriate comments.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

You lose reputation when:

- your question is voted down: −2
- your answer is voted down: −2
- you vote down an answer: −1
- you place a bounty on a question: − full bounty amount
- **one of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags: −100**

Definitely qualifies for a penalty for insulting others. As said earlier, the flags have to be accepted my moderators so it's still a manual process (unless some "special" words are detected in the post, as I read in Brad Laron answer)

Comment: Does the -100 happen for 6 offensive flags on a comment? Or is that just on questions or answers?

Comment: I admit I don't know, although the topic is about Q & A, so comments are probably ruled out. Someone confirms?

Comment: Comments don't have an effect on rep so there is no penalty when those are removed due to abusive flags.

Comment: @rene ...and IIRC even when comment deletion doesn't involve moderators users who tend to get many comments removed by abusive flags are automatically flagged by the system for more thorough mod review. It's [hard to troll](http://i.stack.imgur.com/a0jCv.png) over here