# How should you edit your own answer to keep it up-to-date?

Tags: discussion, answers, editing-help

I've recently seen an outdated answer being completely rewritten by its author to keep it up-to-date:

[image: The post's history in question: complete rewrite with no description]

I appreciate people keeping their answers up-to-date, but this got me wondering: how should you edit your own *completely* outdated answer (to the point it's not applicable anymore) to make it up-to-date? I'm thinking about...

- **Editing the answer and striking through the old, outdated answer.** This is done [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name/2297421#2297421), and seems like a good way to keep the answer up-to-date without losing information even if we don't look at the post's history. *This seems to be the most common.*
- **Keeping the old answer and adding an update noted by "UPDATE"**. I remember seeing a post on meta telling to use "UPDATE:" only when an edit significantly changes a post (which is the case here). This is similar to striking through the old answer in my opinion.
- [**Posting a new answer and potentially editing the old answer to indicate it's outdated**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer), although I think this only applies if the answer is not your own answer.
- **Completely rewriting the answer to update it** (like the author did).

Or maybe something else? What would be the most appropriate thing to do?

After searching on meta, a *related post* would be [Mark questions or answers as out of date](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252520/mark-questions-or-answers-as-out-of-date), but it doesn't seem to answer my question, as I'm asking **how** to edit *our own posts*, while that question seems to be for posts you *found* (that you don't own). Maybe this wouldn't change anything?

Comment: @DavidPostill: the question you've linked to is for other users' posts (in general), not your own answers.

Comment: I know you should ideally edit your own outdated answers to make them up-to-date -- but the question is **how?**

Comment: But the general editing conventions still apply don't they? Just imagine you are editing some others users answer :)

Comment: I'm just not sure, hence I'm asking this question. Your comment could be an answer though :)

Comment: Don't remove any information which could be useful to someone else. In this case, the old API is completely unavailable to everyone, so the old answer (and probably question) is obsolete. That is often not the case, because there is legacy-support. If *your answer* is still useful (though not for those using updated tools), leave it intact, though add a new answer and an edit stating datedness (with details) and maybe linking to your new answer.

Comment: Funny to see the close votes. This so-called "duplicate" question asks **how to edit our own answers**, *not if we should edit or how to edit other users' answers*.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773

Comment: Thanks for the link, @gnat. I should have clarified the question in the post itself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the answer is completely outdated just write a *new* answer and edit the old one stating in which circumstances it works.

Answers never get truly outdated, since there are people using very old hardware and software, so removing the information is surely the wrong thing to do.

Comment: "Answers never get truly outdated" is true except when things are related to security. When a vulnerability is discovered, the answer that was correct can become wrong or even dangerous. But even then, it's better to update the answer to explain why the approach is no longer recommended than to just remove the information.

Answer (score 3):

I personally do the **UPDATE** thing but that's mainly because the questions I tend to answer (javascript, tcl) tend to never be completely out of date.

Javascript for example is notorious for forcing developers to support outdated legacy systems (some of us must still work with IE7) so the old answer remains applicable for a very long time. Not to mention that a lot of people can't simply start using the new updated answer until there's enough people using newer browsers.

Tcl is similar in that there's a lot of old Cisco routers with very old versions of tcl out there. But with tcl the trend is opposite - most people would answer with a modern answer then add an update when the OP states that he's running an older version of tcl. The update is targeted at the OP. The original answer is for posterity.

I guess how you answer really depends on the context of the question. However, I don't think it's good when an answer evolves (gets edited) so much as to become unrelated to the question. The example screenshot you gave however looks OK to me.