# Tool/library/programming language/"what not" comparison place

Tags: feature-request

Not once did we have a question about *what programming language should I use*, or *what is better, Flask or Django*, or *which IDE should I use*, etc. - all of these are rightfully closed because they attract opinion based answers.

And not once did we have someone ask here on meta *why oh why don't we have a place for such question* - which was again, closed - due to the fact that the proposed solution was not viable.

However, I think the reason why this topic keeps popping up is because some of us sometimes want help in deciding what to use, Flask or Django, Eclipse or IntelliJ Idea, and so on.

What I suggest is a place in which:

- we manage categories (IDEs, libraries, programming languages, etc.);
- we manage each individual product (IntelliJ Idea, Java, Django) - just like we do for tags;
- we add there what the product is capable of, based on what the category allows (managed at point #1 above)  (for example, in case of web development frameworks, the following capabilities would be required: title, description, supports templating (yes/no + link to what templating means), built-in database support (yes/no), etc.)
- we provide an interface in which the user

  1. selects the category
  2. a (perhaps limited) number of products
  3. we display what each of them is capable of
  4. and **let the user decide which one is better for them** - no opinion based stuff involved. This was solely the user's decision, **based on facts**

We see such systems when we want to decide what phone to purchase, or what plan is best for me (premium, free, platinum, etc.) - we just need to adapt the system to this requirement.

Of course the whole system needs to be designed to be managed by people with proper permissions (reputation on tags for example) and perhaps requires additional badges to be rewarded and so on, but as a start I'd like to propose this and see what the feedback is - if you think it's doable, what did I miss (if anything) etc.

Comment: Not a bad idea as such, but really beyond Stack Overflow's scope and mission. http://slant.co is doing more or less exactly this

Comment: Wouldn't that go against SO's mission of creating a **long lasting** repository of good questions? Everything in this area would just be good/correct until the next library/IDE/whatever pops up.

Comment: @BDL - answers are outdated in time as well, that's why we have people to manage them - edit them, etc.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - I don't think I've ever seen clearly what SO's scope and mission is really.

Comment: Proposals for new sites should be made on [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/). Do your research and check that there are no prior proposals and that [Software Recommendations](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887/software-recommendations) is not a good fit for this.

Comment: @RobertLongson - I don't want to be recommended something. I just want to see, in a UI, the differences between libraries, tools, IDEs, etc. - I pick the category and products, and the UI shows them to me - different that the Software Recommendation site

Comment: So you suggest a completely different system than the Q and A SO has? I'm not against the idea in general, I just don't see why you think that this is something SO should do.

Comment: @gnat definitely not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: The answer is essentially the same. *Not here*.

Comment: @BDL the documentation attempt was different than the Q and A approach, yet it was implemented

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> we add there what the product is capable of

Well, there's your problem right there.

Comparable software has distinct features. I mean, if it all functioned exactly the same, we'd all use the superior Vim instead of Emacs. Just kidding, I use Nano.

Features come in a matrix. They arise, break and disappear with different releases of a product, their use can be conditional (depending on licensing or intended public or platform to name a few), they can and will be named differently by different vendors.

These features have to be documented by the vendors in the first place, then inventorized and compared against competitors by the users who maintain the matrix. And you'd have to do so rather quickly and often, as new versions of software are released on a daily basis, and licensing conditions (which determine usability of a product) can change on a whim.

All in all, this is a *lot* of work, and there's a *lot* you can do to do it wrong. Stack Overflow users have time and again proven they're not unanimous in how to collaboratively handle documenting changing functionality of software:

- [How to deal with obsolete answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11705/how-to-deal-with-obsolete-answers)
- [How to deal with hugely upvoted, bad and outdated answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272570/how-to-deal-with-hugely-upvoted-bad-and-outdated-answers)
- [What's the policy on down voting previously correct but now outdated answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265749/whats-the-policy-on-down-voting-previously-correct-but-now-outdated-answers)
- [Should I update very old answers when the solution becomes deprecated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288987/should-i-update-very-old-answers-when-the-solution-becomes-deprecated)
- [How should you edit your own answer to keep it up-to-date?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268300/how-should-you-edit-your-own-answer-to-keep-it-up-to-date)
- [Good question, old version-dependent answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer)

So I'd say: no, we shouldn't do such comparisons here on Stack Overflow or any other site on the network. The users nor the software are ready for it.

Comment: Last line: Imo, replace _"Overflow"_ with _"Exchange"_. +1 either way.